# How create custom iterator that skips empty value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, iterator, javascript-objects

### Cusomt iterator in Javascript

Hi,
I would like to create a Javascript class that overrides `Symbol.iterator` in order to skip the data that are `null` or `undefined`.

#### Example

```js
  const simple = new SimpleClass([
    {
      fields: `a`,
    },
    {
      fields: `b`,
    },
    {
      fields: undefined,
    },
    {
      fields: null,
    },
    {
      fields: `e`,
    },
  ]);

  for (const val of simple) {
    console.log(val); // a b e
  }
```

Here is where I've started: [Defining an iterable with a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#defining_an_iterable_with_a_class)

Can you help me to draft a solution for my use-case?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you tried. We're not going to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class SimpleClass {
  #items
  constructor(items) {
    this.#items = items
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (const item of this.#items) {
      if (item.fields !== null && item.fields !== undefined) {
        yield item.fields
      }
    }
  }
}

const simple = new SimpleClass([{
    fields: `a`,
  },
  {
    fields: `b`,
  },
  {
    fields: undefined,
  },
  {
    fields: null,
  },
  {
    fields: `e`,
  },
]);

for (const val of simple) {
  console.log(val); // a b e
}
```